# terminal is not accessible

Tags: command-line, vmware

my desktop went away. and I couldn't access any program. and I just see the purple screen. the only thing I could do is to open the home. plus i couldn't access the terminal Ctrl+alt+T is not working , how should I overcome this issue and what happenend ?
thank you inadvance

ps : I run `ubuntu 14.04` in `vmware` machine

**Edit** : this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) was not resolved my problem because `unity plugin` was not appearing in the `compizconfig` and  the problem was due to deleting `python` package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Comment: @muru,thanks .at first I got to step 3 and then it freezed, I restart the system and go through the step .. but there where no `unity plugin` and there is an error displayed on `tty1` : `ccsm:2588:IBUS-Warrnings :unable to connect to ibus:could not connect:connection refused`

Comment: Did you login to the GUI before switching to tty1?

Comment: yes I just get to see the wallpaper and then I follow the steps

Comment: If you run `DISPLAY=:0 gnome-terminal` in the TTY, does the terminal show up in the GUI?

Comment: I `power off` the `Ubuntu` , it will take some time.sorry

Comment: @muru.it said that it wasn't installed, I installed it but in the installation process :`(gconftool-2:3238):GConf-Warning**Client failed to connect to D-BUS daemon: unable to auto-launch a dbus daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11 `

Comment: Which is weird. Did you uninstall something before all this happened? What happens when you do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: yes I was trying to uninstall `python` and `igraph_python` and some other packages but during these times I open up some terminals, and I can't recall but the last terminal changed to something else, and from that time I couldn't open up a terminal and when I restart it these all happened

Comment: You **CANNOT** uninstall python. Too many things depend on it.

Comment: oh!so then after installing ubuntu-desktop which is in the progress, I should install python? with this command :`sudo apt-get install python` because I had some problem with matching versions before

Comment: No, `ubuntu-desktop` will pull in python as well. If you had problems with python versions, you should consider using a local version with virtualenvs.

Comment: Ok, Thank you so much for your helps and information.

Comment: @f.a: Did this resolve your problem? If so, give muru a ping so he can convert his comment to a proper answer.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, yes,installing `ubuntu-desktop` did solve my problem.

Comment: @muru, please convert your comment to an answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a pretty core package, a lot of things depend on it (including much of the GUI). You can re-install the Ubuntu GUI using:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

if you problems with Python versions, it's best to leave the system Python alone and use [virtualenvs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1108999/2072269).